# Access to method pointer to protected method?

Tags: c++, protected, specifications

This code:

```
class B {
 protected:
  void Foo(){}
}

class D : public B {
 public:
  void Baz() {
    Foo();
  }
  void Bar() {
    printf("%x\n", &B::Foo);
  }
}
```

gives this error:

```
t.cpp: In member function 'void D::Bar()':
Line 3: error: 'void B::Foo()' is protected
```

- Why can I call a protected method but not take its address?
- Is there a way to mark something fully accessible from derived classes rather than only accessible from derived classes *and* in relation to said derived class?

---

BTW: [This looks related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628421/calling-protected-method-in-base-class-via-pointer-to-base-class-in-derived-class) but what I'm looking for a reference to where this is called out in the spec or the like (and hopefully that will lead to how to get things to work the way I was expecting).

Answer (score 23):

You can take the address through `D` by writing `&D::Foo`, instead of `&B::Foo`.

See this compiles fine : http://www.ideone.com/22bM4

But this doesn't compile (your code) : http://www.ideone.com/OpxUy

---

**Why can I call a protected method but not take its address?**

You cannot take its address by writing `&B::Foo` because `Foo` is a *protected* member, you cannot access it from outside `B`, not even its address.  But writing `&D::Foo`, you can, because `Foo` becomes a member of `D` through inheritance, and you can get its address, no matter whether its private, protected or public.

`&B::Foo` has same restriction as `b.Foo()` and `pB->Foo()` has, in the following code:

```
void Bar() {
    B b;
    b.Foo();     //error - cannot access protected member!
    B *pB = this;
    pB->Foo();   //error - cannot access protected member!
  }
```

See error at ideone : http://www.ideone.com/P26JT

Comment: Your post doesn't answer "Why can I call a protected method but not take its address?".

Comment: For reason to complex to go into, I don't want to (lexically) reference the Derived class at this point.

Comment: @Prasoon: Yes. It doesn't answer (that part). Did I say it does? It partly answers his question which has two parts.

Comment: @Nawaz : No why would someone possibly say that his answer is complete? People expect posters to post complete answers.

Comment: @Prasoon: Who said my answer is complete?

Comment: @Prasoon: *People expect posters to post complete answers*... I would say "Good expectation". But I answer to the extent I know.

Comment: @Prasoon: +1 for an incomplete answer. { GodwinsLaw::Invoke(); }

Comment: @BCS (and @Prasoon too) : Now it isn't incomplete :D

Comment: @ the 1st line: for some reason I hadn't know this was possible. Cool! So, aside from all people's grumbling about completeness, your answer would have told me something useful even before your edits.

Comment: 9 years later, the ideone links are dead

Answer (score 6):

This is because an object of a derived class can only access protected members of a base class if it's *the same object*. Allowing you to take the pointer of a protected member function would make it impossible to maintain this restriction, as function pointers do not carry any of this information with them.

Comment: I don't want that restriction. Is there a way to make things work the way I was expecting? (See edit)

Comment: @BCS I'm not really sure why the same-object restriction is there in the first place. A clue to what you're trying to accomplish with this would be helpful.

Comment: @BCS Practically speaking no because what you're asking for is a change to the C++ standard. You could always fork a C++ compiler and modify it allow such a construct but then it wouldn't be C++ anymore.

Comment: @BCS - If you were allowed to do what you want, the `protected` keyword would be practically useless because anyone could get access to other classes' protected parts by just deriving a dummy class from it and create a pointer-to-member. This doesn't work, by design!

Answer (score 3):

I believe `protected` doesn't work the way you think it does in C++. In C++ `protected` only allows access to parent members of *its own instance* NOT arbitrary instances of the parent class. As noted in other answers, taking the address of a parent function would violate this.

If you want access to arbitrary instances of a parent, you could have the parent class friend the child, or make the parent method `public`. There's no way to change the meaning of `protected` to do what you want it to do within a C++ program.

But what are you *really* trying to do here? Maybe we can solve *that* problem for you.

Comment: Making things public allows non derived classes access (bad). Using `friend` requires the author of `B` to know in advance of all derived classes (bad) and also gives them access to things that shouldn't be accessible (bad).

Answer (score 3):

> Why can I call a protected method but not take its address?

This question has an error. You cannot do a call either

```
B *self = this;
self->Foo(); // error either!
```

As another answer says if you access the non-static protected member by a `D`, *then* you can. Maybe you want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c/1065606#1065606)?

---

As a summary, read [this issue report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1007).

Answer (score 1):

> Your post doesn't answer "Why can I
>   call a protected method but not take
>   its address?"

```
class D : public B {
 public:
  void Baz() {
    // this line
    Foo();
    // is shorthand for:
    this->Foo();
  }
  void Bar() {
    // this line isn't, it's taking the address of B::Foo
    printf("%x\n", &B::Foo);

    // not D:Foo, which would work
    printf("%x\n", &D::Foo);

  }
}
```

Comment: That may be true/relevant from a language purist standpoint, but the fact of the matter at the machine level is that the functions `F::Foo` and `D::Foo` are the same thing (proof: a derived class can call a protected base class method even across separate compilation).

Comment: @BCS - Yes, but you can only access D::Foo if you actually have a D object. You cannot use that pointer to access Foo that is a member of any other class. That's on purpose!

Comment: My assertion is that `D::Foo` *is* `B::Foo` (under the covers) so in this case I have two ways to do things that end up doing exactly the same thing and only one is legal. This seems very contrived if you look at it from the standpoint of what actually happens on the CPU. In effect, I'm bitching that what C++ chose as its reference-to-method isn't low-level enough for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to mark something fully accessible from derived classes rather than only accessible from derived classes and in relation to said derived class?

Yes, with the [passkey idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324898/can-we-increase-the-re-usability-of-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern). :)

```
class derived_key
{
    // Both private.
    friend class derived;

    derived_key() {}
};

class base
{
public:
    void foo(derived_key) {}
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    void bar() { foo(derived_key()); }
};
```

Since only `derived` has access to the contructor of `derived_key`, only that class can call the `foo` method, even though it's public.
The obvious problem with that approach is the fact, that you need to friend every possible derived class, which is pretty error prone. Another possible (and imho better way in your case) is to friend the base class and expose a protected `get_key` method.

```
class base_key
{
    friend class base;

    base_key() {}
};

class base
{
public:
    void foo(base_key) {}

protected:
    base_key get_key() const { return base_key(); }
};

class derived1 : public base
{
public:
    void bar() { foo(get_key()); }
};

class derived2 : public base
{
public:
    void baz() { foo(get_key()); }
};

int main()
{
  derived1 d1;
  d1.bar(); // works
  d1.foo(base_key()); // error: base_key ctor inaccessible
  d1.foo(d1.get_key()); // error: get_key inaccessible

  derived2 d2;
  d2.baz(); // works again
}
```

See the full example [on Ideone](http://ideone.com/tDdkB).

Answer (score 0):

Standard reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access#Protected_member_access

```
When a pointer to a protected member is formed, it must use a derived class in its declaration:
```

```
struct Base {
  protected:
    int i;
};
 
struct Derived : Base {
  void f() {
//  int Base::* ptr = &Base::i;    // error: must name using Derived
    int Base::* ptr = &Derived::i; // OK
  }
};
```