# Why is it impossible to get a pointer to a protected method of the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class A {
public:
   A() {auto tmp = &A::foo;}
protected:
   void foo() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
   B() {auto tmp = &A::foo;}
};
```

Class `A` compiles no problem. Class `B` yields a compilation error:

> 'A::foo' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'

Why is that, what's the rationale? Is there a way to circumvent this (if I need that pointer for a callback, `std::function` etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were able to take a pointer to `A::foo`, you could use it to invoke `foo` on an object of type `A` or of type `C` derived from `A`:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    void xx(A a) { auto tmp = &A::foo; a.*tmp(); }  // illegal
}
```

Instead, take a pointer to `B::foo`; this is fine because you can only use it on objects of type `B`, your own class.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is that, what's the rationale?

In general, a derived class can only access protected members of the same derived class, not of the base class itself or arbitrary classes with the same base class. So `B` can access protected members of `A` via `B`, but not directly via `A`.

> Is there a way to circumvent this?

The inherited member is also a member of `B`, and can be accessed as such:

```
auto tmp = &B::foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably for safety.  If you could get a pointer to that member and give it to absolutely anyone without having some kind of alarm bell going off, that would be risky.

Here's *a* workaround (others may know better):

```
class A {
public:
    A() {auto tmp = &A::foo;}
protected:
    void foo() {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {auto tmp = &B::foo;}
};
```

EDIT - thought you might need a using A::foo but you don't even need that.  Works without.  See:

[Access to method pointer to protected method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822421/access-to-method-pointer-to-protected-method)

Comment: "*Presumably for safety*" - there are many ways to give pointer to member to anyone

Answer (score 1):

You can access it through `B`, that is :

```
class B : public A {
public:
   B() {auto tmp = &B::foo;}
};
```

You cannot access `&A::Foo` from outside `B`, since it is protected, but you can through **inheritance** (since `Foo` becomes a member of `B` through inheritance), that is, by calling `&B::Foo`